# single column with multiple values match multiple values sql

Tags: mysql, sql, tagging

I have the table `newsarchive` in which there is a `tags` column where I can enter multiple values separated by comma. I have a page in which the news matching the tags specified with the `newsarchive.tags` will be shown. The tags in the page can also have multiple values.

Now I want to  get the records that matches the tags from page with `newsarchive.tags`. Is there a SQL statement to achieve the result?

```
CREATE TABLE newsarchive ( 
    newsid int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
    headline text NOT NULL, 
    article text NOT NULL, 
    pdate date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00', 
    tags text NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (newsid) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=107 ;
```

### Example

```
newsarchive.tags of record#1="Nepal, Everest, Kathmandu"

newsarchive.tags of record#2="Kathmandu,Pokhara"

newsarchive.tags of record#3="Everest,Pokhara"

tags(in page)="Nepal, Kathmandu"
```

### Result should be:

```
record#1
record#2
```

I am using the `SELECT` statement with `IN` as

```
SELECT * FROM newsarchive WHERE tags IN ('Nepal','Kathmandu') ORDER BY postdate;
```

### Note:

I will be happy if the record with most tags matched appears first.

Comment: I don't understand your example.  can you please show the table structure?

Comment: CREATE TABLE `newsarchive` (
  `newsid` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `headline` text NOT NULL,
  `article` text NOT NULL,
  `pdate` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `tags` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`newsid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=107 ;

Comment: If this is a table in a relational database it would appear that it hasn't been properly normalized, as having multiple values in one cell breaks the first normal form. This opens up for all sorts of issues, and what you should do is to normalize it in my opinion.

Comment: @facebook-740957561, can you add that create statement to your question above? And did you try `LIKE` instead of `IN` for example:`WHERE tags like '%Nepal%' or tags like '%Kathmandu%'`

Comment: What flavor of sql are we talking here?  MySQL??

Comment: @rs, my tags at the page is dynamic(meaning it is not just limited to above words but more) and i don't want to program it every time I change the tags.

Comment: @all, thanks all for the quick and suggestive comments. maybe i follow 'rs' suggestion but to make the code adaptive.                            $q="SELECT * FROM newsarchive WHERE  ";
foreach ($tags as $tag)
 $q.="tags LIKE '%".$tag ."%' or ";
$q=substr($q,0,strlen($q)-3);
$q.=" ORDER BY pdate DESC";

Answer (score 0):

Using `where tags in` isn't going to work for your scenario.

The best approach would be to put those tags into a related table linked via foreign key to the record.

If you do not have the ability to change the schema and your working with an RDBMS system that supports it you'll want to look into [full text searching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) on MySQL or ([SQL Server link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)) in order to search that delimited string.

Outside of full text you'll have to split up the strings via their delimiter (a comma in this case) and search them individually via temp table, table variable, or other means.  I've seen [xml approaches](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2009/12/delimited-string-tennis-anyone.html) to searching delimited strings that follow that rough concept on SQL Server.

On MySQL you may have to write your own [string splitting function](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,78776,78776).  Read through responses to linked question to see example approaches to splitting in MySQL.

If you have to store multi value data in a single column (not recommended) then usually XML is a better way to go than delimited strings.  MySQL offers some support for xpath queries etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in a poor structure.  You should have a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE newstags ( 
    newstagsid int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    newsid int(11) not null,
    tag text not null 
    PRIMARY KEY (newstagsid)
)
```

This would have one tag per story.  An even better structure would be to store the tags in a separate table, and use `tagid` here instead of `tag`.

But you don't have that.  What can you do?  You can parse the tags entered by the use in php.  Then construct a SQL statement with the following condition:

```
(concat(',', tags, ',') like concat('%,', USERTAGS1, '%,') or
 concat(',', tags, ',') like concat('%,', USERTAGS2, '%,') or
 . . .
 concat(',', tags, ',') like concat('%,', USERTAGSn, '%,')
)
```

Another approach is to build a full text index on the tags, and then to use `contains`.